# USING $THIS in PHP

Tags: php

In my code I'm trying to call a function that is inside of another function. I'm trying to pass the $results var to the NVPToArray() function and return the result. After that, I want to echo the result, which will be an array. I keep getting an error saying that the function is undefined so I'm pretty sure that I'm not calling the function properly.

```
<?php


class Process extends BaseController {

        // Function to convert NTP string to an array

        public function postPurchase() {
                // Include config file
                include(app_path().'/includes/paypal_config.php');
                $result = curl_exec($curl);
                curl_close($curl);

                // Parse the API response
                $nvp_response_array = parse_str($result);

                // Function to convert NTP string to an array
                function NVPToArray($NVPString)
                {
                    $proArray = array();
                    while(strlen($NVPString))
                    {
                        // name
                        $keypos= strpos($NVPString,'=');
                        $keyval = substr($NVPString,0,$keypos);
                        // value
                        $valuepos = strpos($NVPString,'&') ? strpos($NVPString,'&'): strlen($NVPString);
                        $valval = substr($NVPString,$keypos+1,$valuepos-$keypos-1);
                        // decoding the respose
                        $proArray[$keyval] = urldecode($valval);
                        $NVPString = substr($NVPString,$valuepos+1,strlen($NVPString));
                    }
                    return $proArray;
                }

                NVPToArray($this->$result);

                echo $proArray;

        }


}

?>
```

Comment: looks like you're trying to call the function `NVPT` not `NVPToArray()` ... also, I recommend against nesting functions like that as it makes code much less readable.

Comment: Why are you defining NVPToArray inside the other function ? Why don't you put it in the root of the class ?

Comment: Does your edit indicate that `NVPT()` was a typo in your original post?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't declare a function within a function in PHP, it will cause an error if you run the function more than once. Also, your function is named `NVPToArray`, but you are calling `NVPT`. Try something more like this (it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do in `postPurchase`).

```
<?php

class Process extends BaseController {

    // Function to convert NTP string to an array

    public function postPurchase() {
        // Include config file
        include(app_path().'/includes/paypal_config.php');
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        // Parse the API response
        $nvp_response_array = parse_str($result);

        echo $this->NVPToArray($result);
    }

    // Function to convert NTP string to an array
    public function NVPToArray($NVPString)
    {
        $proArray = array();
        while(strlen($NVPString))
        {
            // name
            $keypos= strpos($NVPString,'=');
            $keyval = substr($NVPString,0,$keypos);
            // value
            $valuepos = strpos($NVPString,'&') ? strpos($NVPString,'&'): strlen($NVPString);
            $valval = substr($NVPString,$keypos+1,$valuepos-$keypos-1);
            // decoding the respose
            $proArray[$keyval] = urldecode($valval);
            $NVPString = substr($NVPString,$valuepos+1,strlen($NVPString));
       }
       return $proArray;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: +1 This code is way better organized than the original code OP posted.

Comment: I fixed the code with your improvements. The code I previously uploaded was a trimmed version of the original. Here is the original. I'm trying to call the property "nvp_response_array" and call the NVPToArray() on it but for some reason it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting undefined function because you are calling `NVPT()` which not exists.

You should call `NVPToArray()` function.

And about the `$this`, as your `$result` var is defined inside the function you don't need to use it. You can call it with just `$result`.

You would use it, if you had something like:

```
class T {
...
    public $result;

    function yourF(){
         ....
         echo $this->result;
    }
}
```