# syntax error, unexpected 'NVPToArray' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Tags: php

I started learning PHP this week and I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I'm trying to call the function NVPToArray() on the property nvp_response_array. The function is supposed to make an array from the property. I also tried passing a string in the argument of the function but it seems to expect a string, which seems odd. I am just beginning to grasp the fundamentals of PHP and I would really appreciate it if someone helped me! Thank you!

```
<?php
```

class Process extends BaseController {

```
    // Function to convert NTP string to an array

    public function postPurchase() {
            // Include config file
            include(app_path().'/includes/paypal_config.php');
            //Config::get('paypal_api');

            // Store request params in an array
            $request_params = array(
                 'METHOD' => 'DoDirectPayment',
                 'USER' => $api_username,
                 'PWD' => $api_password,
                 'SIGNATURE' => $api_signature,
                 'VERSION' => $api_version,
                 'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
                 'IPADDRESS' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                 'CREDITCARDTYPE' => 'MasterCard',
                 'ACCT' => '5522340006063638',
                 'EXPDATE' => '022013',
                 'CVV2' => '456',
                 'FIRSTNAME' => 'Tester',
                 'LASTNAME' => 'Testerson',
                 'STREET' => '707 W. Bay Drive',
                 'CITY' => 'Largo',
                 'STATE' => 'FL',
                 'COUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
                 'ZIP' => '33770',
                 'AMT' => '100.00',
                 'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
                 'DESC' => 'Testing Payments Pro'
            );

            // Loop through $request_params array to generate the NVP string.
            $nvp_string = '';
            foreach($request_params as $var=>$val)
            {
                $nvp_string .= '&'.$var.'='.urlencode($val);
            }

            // Send NVP string to PayPal and store response
            $curl = curl_init();

               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp_string);

            $result = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);

            // Parse the API response
            $nvp_response_array = parse_str($result);

    }

  // Function to convert NTP string to an array
      public function NVPToArray($NVPString)
      {
          $proArray = array();
          while(strlen($NVPString))
          {
              // name
              $keypos= strpos($NVPString,'=');
              $keyval = substr($NVPString,0,$keypos);
              // value
              $valuepos = strpos($NVPString,'&') ? strpos($NVPString,'&'): strlen($NVPString);
              $valval = substr($NVPString,$keypos+1,$valuepos-$keypos-1);
              // decoding the respose
              $proArray[$keyval] = urldecode($valval);
              $NVPString = substr($NVPString,$valuepos+1,strlen($NVPString));
         }
         return $proArray;
      }

      NVPToArray($this->nvp_response_array);
```

}

?>

Comment: [**It was working**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24582172/) and now this, what changed since? It was working, right? Otherwise, you wouldn't have accepted that answer.

Comment: Curious, and possibly a silly question, but `....` that's not part of your actual code is it? Or is that "there's code here, but I won't bother showing it".?

Comment: Are we to guess the syntax error line number? Is it perhaps the attempted function invocation outside of the method body? Why is that there?

Comment: Why are you trying to call a function in the middle of defining a class?

Comment: Adding all the code would turn people away and give me even more dislikes for my question. I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible. I really wish that people would acknowledge that I am a beginner in this field but they keep voting down my questions. Thats why I'm trying to keep them as simple as possible to avoid dislikes

Comment: No problemo. Like I said, was curious. One never knows. Food for thought, if it's code replacement, use something like `// there's more code here, but irrelevant` type of thing. ;-) I just needed to ask.

Comment: Your questions are disliked because they too are much code *in comparison* to your explanations on what you're trying to accomplish and prior attempts. Explaining why `NVPToArray` won't work there would require a whole OOP tutorial. Stack Overflow does in fact appreciate newcomer questions, but they ought to be better researched and not just syntax errors. Your whole NVPToArray seems to be a super long-winded [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) reimplementation, btw.

Comment: Thanks mario. I will try replacing the code

Comment: @user3216221 - I don't understand what your question is - you don't say what problem you're getting right now. I will say that your `NVPToArray` function is returning an array, but when you call it at the end, you don't assign the return value to anything - is that what you mean? Otherwise, could you edit your question and add a little more explanation? Does the code give you an error message when you try to run it? A blank screen? Does it do what it's supposed to do? If not,what does it do?